# In C++ (arduino) how do I use a field in construction of another field

Tags: c++, syntax, arduino, header-files

I am attempting to create this header file:

```
#define MqttConfig_h

#include "Arduino.h"
#include <PubSubClient.h>         // MQTT client
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>      // ESP8266 Core WiFi Library
#include <Config.h>

class MqttConfig
{
  public:
    MqttConfig();
    void initMQTT();

  private:
    String _mqttServer;
    String _mqttPrefix;
    WiFiClient _wifi;
    PubSubClient _mqttClient(_wifi);     ****** ERROR HERE  *******
};

#endif
```

I've tried various ways to make it work:

```
// This seemed logical to me
PubSubClient _mqttClient(WiFiClient{});

// This was an attempt to read the field and pass it back
WiFiClient GetWiFiClient();       
PubSubClient _mqttClient(GetWiFiClient());

// This compiles, but does something I don't understand
WiFiClient GetWiFiClient();       
PubSubClient _mqttClient(WiFiClient);
```

What is the right way to "chain up fields" in the header file? I'll note that I don't care about a reference to the _wifi object, I'm making it because the constructor of the PubSubClient object wants it..

Answer (score 2):

In general, you initialize fields in your constructor:

```
class MqttConfig
{
  public:
    MqttConfig();

  private:
    PubSubClient _mqttClient;
};

// ...
MqttConfig::MqttConfig()
    : _mqttClient(WiFiClient{})
{
}
```

---

As for your last attempt:

```
// This compiles, but does something I don't understand
WiFiClient GetWiFiClient();       
PubSubClient _mqttClient(WiFiClient);
```

These are method declarations.